# ASP.Net C# Destroy Form Session on browser back

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, captcha

Hey guys I've got a form ok? And when I submit it everything is cool but when I hit the back button on my browser the form is completed with my previous credentials. And the most important is that I use captcha sessions from aspx files and their class files. Even if I have the captcha text field getting empty each time the page is refreshed, the session stays the same. How do I stop that please?
Here is the ASPX file of the captcha:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Captcha.aspx.cs" Inherits="Captcha" %>
```

and here is it's CS file:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using SRVTextToImage;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;

public partial class Captcha : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CaptchaRandomImage CI = new CaptchaRandomImage();
        string captchaText = CI.GetRandomString(6);
        Session["captchaText"] = captchaText;
        CI.GenerateImage(captchaText, 100, 38, Color.DarkRed, Color.LightGray);
        this.Response.Clear();
        this.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
        CI.Image.Save(this.Response.OutputStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        CI.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to clear the textboxes on browser back?
From http://forums.asp.net/t/1445431.aspx?Browser+back+button+not+clear+the+form

You can use a script to clear the textboxes on page load, and also

```
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now);
```

So that the page will not be fetched from cache on brower back.

Comment: Well thanks but that's not was I was talking about... I want to reset the captcha session...